# Gmail API insert message throws - Bad Request (400)

Tags: java, google-api-java-client, gmail-api

Trying to insert message loaded from MimeMessage (as shown in gmail api example), some 
messages are passing fine, but some throws this:

```
    com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Bad Request</H1>
<H2>Error 400</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>

    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1049)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
```

The code is next:

```
     final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     mime.writeTo(baos);
     String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(baos.toByteArray());
     tmpMail = new Message();
     tmpMail.setRaw(encodedEmail);
     client.users().messages().insert(this.taskInfo.getTargetAccount(), tmpMail).execute();
```

Without any other information, what could be a possible reason for that error ?

Thanks.

**UPD. Looks like messages larger than 10Mb are giving this error. Google guys, can you advise ? Thanks**

Comment: Are you sending this from a server?

Comment: Also, will you please post the code that sends this error?

Comment: @abalos I'm sending this from laptop , please see code in the edited post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what I have:-) A 35 MB limit is clearly documented here (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert, 4th line), not a problem for most because their existing e-mail systems limit email size to a somewhat smaller number.

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
message.writeTo(output);
final String raw = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(output.toByteArray());
if (raw.length() > 35000000) {
    System.err.println("Message too large, skipping");
} else {
    try {
           getGmailService()
                        .users()
                        .messages()
                        .insert("me",
                                new Message().setRaw(raw)).execute();
```

Comment: Looks like there is a differences between someone who documented it and someone who coded a server side :)

Comment: Yes, also the GMail documentation (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6584?hl=en) lists 25MB as the limit, that would be approximately 31 MB Base64 encoded

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the media "/upload" method to send something that large.  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads

Comment: How can be /upload used in GMail API Java SDK ? Thanks

Comment: In the GMail API Java explanation method insert page described that limitation is 35mb : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert . Please advise.

Comment: The 35MB is the enforced limit, yes.  The other, lower (10MB?) limit you're running into is an unpublished infrastructure limitation of the www.googleapis.com frontend when not using the /batch URL.  I imagine that doc you're referring to is autogenerated and doesn't distinguish/detail this limitation.  In general, if you're sending more than a couple MB best to use /upload as it's more efficient and supports other niceties, etc.

Comment: The document I'm referring is Gmail API java, with example of how to insert any message up to 35 mb and I don't think it's auto generated. There is no /upload functionality in the GMail Java API, how it can be used ? And, actually I'm confused, what should I use and why there is a limitation that doesn't documented for the insert / import method.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, the method insert (that I'm using) is doing /upload - this is what in the documentation for insert : "This method provides media upload functionality through two separate URIs. For more details, see the document on media upload.

Upload URI, for media upload requests:
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages Please advise.